# QML.NET - Convert C# Class Into QML List Model

Tags: c#, qt, qml

I am looking into QML.NET's TableView. I have a C# object class (Person : ID and Name). I would like to populate the QML Table View with my C# class (Person).

Anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: there is [qmlnet](https://github.com/qmlnet/qmlnet) that allows to use .NET types in QML but for me it looks very very strange idea

Comment: Yes, qml.net is the one I am looking into. It works quite well from my testing. Encountered issue passing in C# object and populate the QML TableView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use the `Net.toListModel(personModel.personList)` method to convert your `List<Person>` into model that your QML TableView can use.

## Example

### PersonPage.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Controls 2.1
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import Features 1.0

Page {
    Pane {
        id: detsPane
        anchors.fill: parent
        contentHeight: pane.implicitHeight

        TableView {
            id: personTable
            implicitWidth:  pane.width -20

            TableViewColumn { 
                role: "id"
                title: "Identifier"
            }
            TableViewColumn {
                role: "name"
                title: "Name"
            }

            model: personModel
        }

        PersonModel {
            id: personModel
            Component.onCompleted: {
                personTable.model = Net.toListModel(personModel.personList) 
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

### PersonModel.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace GUI.Models
{
    public class PersonModel 
    {
        public class Person
        {
            public string Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }

        public List<Person> PersonList { get; } = new List<Person>()
        {
            new Person(){Id="BB", Name="Bob Bobber" },
            new Person(){Id="RM", Name="Rod McRod" }
        };
    }
}
```

This will produce the following:
[image: Application Screenshot]

Nb. the qml page has been added to the example project from the project page. `Main.qml`:

```
    Drawer {
...        
            model: ListModel {
                ListElement { title: "Contacts"; source: "pages/PersonPage.qml" }
            }
...
    }
```

Also assumes that you have registered your model in `Program.cs`

```
   Qml.Net.Qml.RegisterType<PersonModel>("Features");
```